# How to use reducer in redux in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, mern

I am using `Redux` for state management, I have faced an issue in reducer function
here is the image of my console, You can see the Product Action is providing my data but the reducer is not passing on my function

[image]

here is my code of ProductAction:

```
export const getProductsbyFind = (myvariable) =>async (dispatch)=>{
    try {
        console.log(myvariable)
        dispatch({type: ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST_BY_ID})
        const{ data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/product/${myvariable}`)
        console.log(data)
        dispatch({
            type: ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS_BY_ID,
            payload: data
        })
        
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type:ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL,
            payload: error.response.data.message
        })
        
    }
}
```

here is the code of Reducer:

```
export const productReducersById = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST_BY_ID:
            return {
                loading: true,
                products: []
            }
        case ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS_BY_ID:
            return {
                loading: false,
                products: action.payload.products,
                productsCount: action.payload.productsCount
            }
        case UPDATE_QUANTITY_BY_ID:
            const { index, quantity } = action.payload;
            const prods = state.products.map((p, i) => {
                if (i !== index)
                    return p;
                return {
                    ...p,
                    quantity
                }
            });
            return {
                loading: true,
                products: prods
            }

        case ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL_BY_ID:
            return {
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload
            }
        case CLEAR_ERRORS_BY_ID:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: null
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

here is the code of my page where I want to get my data:

```
  const { loading, products, error, productCount } = useSelector(state => state.products);
  console.log(products)
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProductsbyFind(myvariable));
  }, [dispatch])
```

Comment: I think it's a spelling error. Your response has  product as a key name but your reducer is accessing it via the  action.payload.products

Comment: kindly mention me where is the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your reducer:

```js
  case ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS_BY_ID:
      return {
          loading: false,
-         products: action.payload.products,
+         products: action.payload.product,
          productsCount: action.payload.productsCount
      }
```

(Also, `productsCount` does not exist in your payload, so that will become `undefined`.)

Comment: still same console result

Comment: i removed productsCount and action.payload.products but still same console

Comment: Also what happens in your example is that your reducer assumes that `products` are all arrays. Your example code is just a single `product` object. So what happens is that you change your array into an object. You probably want to have `products: [action.payload.product]`. Or if you want to keep previous products, you want `products: [...state.products, action.state.product]`

Comment: got it ... it's really helpful for me